# Stored procedure to get date time difference

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Location_table:

```
Locid   Locname
--------------
8       Blooimng dale
```

LocVtypeAssign_tbl:

```
locid       vtid
----------- -----------
8           7
8           8
```

Transaction_tbl:

```
transactID   Locid   vtid  dtime                       Paydate
---------    -----   ----  -----------------------     ----------------------    
7497         8       7     2013-06-28 14:39:34.000     2013-06-28 18:28:20.000
7500         8       8     2013-06-28 14:41:57.000     NULL
```

If I pass Locid 8 how i can get sum of date difference of vtid 7 and vtid 8. i am finding date difference using this formula:

```
sum(DATEDIFF(hour,t.Paydate,t.DelDate))
```

Expected output:

```
location        datediff of 7       datediff of 8
Blooming Dale   2206:30321:73242    235:3373:56915
```

Is there any way to write stored procedure for getting this output?

I tried the query like this:

```
SELECT convert(varchar(10),sum(DATEDIFF(hour,t.Paydate,t.DelDate)))+':' 
      +convert(varchar(10),sum(DATEDIFF(minute,t.Paydate,t.DelDate)% 60)) + ':' 
      +convert(varchar(10),sum(DATEDIFF(SECOND,t.Paydate,t.DelDate)% 60)) 
       AS ' HH:MM:SS'
FROM Transaction_tbl t 
WHERE t.Locid=8 group by vtid
```

I am getting output like this:

```
HH:MM:SS
----------------
2206:30321:73242
235:3373:56915
```

Comment: I can't see DelDate anywhere in any of your tables. I don't get the logic here, how did you get 2206:30321:73242 and 235:3373:56915? What do the numbers mean and how does the math work?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like the following:

```
SELECT l.Locname AS location,
  convert(varchar(10),sum(DATEDIFF(hour,t7.Paydate,t7.DelDate)))+':' 
  + convert(varchar(10),sum(DATEDIFF(minute,t7.Paydate,t7.DelDate)% 60)) + ':' 
  + convert(varchar(10),sum(DATEDIFF(SECOND,t7.Paydate,t7.DelDate)% 60)) 
  AS 'datediff of 7',
  convert(varchar(10),sum(DATEDIFF(hour,t8.Paydate,t8.DelDate)))+':' 
  + convert(varchar(10),sum(DATEDIFF(minute,t8.Paydate,t8.DelDate)% 60)) + ':' 
  + convert(varchar(10),sum(DATEDIFF(SECOND,t8.Paydate,t8.DelDate)% 60)) 
  AS 'datediff of 8'
FROM Location_tbl l
JOIN Transaction_tbl t7
ON t7.locid = l.locid AND t7.vtid = 7
JOIN Transaction_tbl t8
ON t8.locid = l.locid AND t8.vtid = 8
WHERE l.Locid = 8
```

Generalizing this to a different set of datediff offsets is left as an exercise for the reader.  You can also check out [PIVOT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx).